# Unable to update SQLite database in iOS

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am trying to insert values into my SQLite database that the user enters from UITextFields on the screen.  I am able to open the database, create the table without any issues, but my problem occurs when I try to insert the values into my SQLite database, I get the following error:

```
2013-06-25 14:35:12.074 BPApp[11317:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[BPAppMainViewController saveEntry:], /Users/capris/Documents/Documents/BPApp/BPApp/BPAppMainViewController.m:81
2013-06-25 14:35:12.075 BPApp[11317:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not update table'
```

Here is my method where I do the insert:

```
- (IBAction)saveEntry:(id)sender {

int systolic = [_systolicText.text intValue];
int diastolic = [_diastolicText.text intValue];
NSString *comments = [_commentsText text];
NSDate *theDate = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"%@, %d, %d, %@", theDate, systolic, diastolic, comments);

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO summary ('theDate', 'systolic', 'diastolic', 'comments') VALUES ('%@', '%d', '%d', '%@')", theDate, systolic, diastolic, comments];

char *err;

if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Error message is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");

} else {

    NSLog(@"table updated");
}

_systolicText.text = @"";
_diastolicText.text = @"";
_commentsText.text = @"";
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I am following the set of tutorials found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxoeZ-1yCMc).

I am suspicious that there may be an error with my SQL statement, but I can't seem to find anything wrong with it.  Other relevant methods are here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self openDB];
    [self createTable:@"summary" withField1:@"theDate" withField2:@"systolic" withField3:@"diastolic" withField4:@"comments"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


- (void) createTable: (NSString *)tableName
          withField1: (NSString *)field1
          withField2: (NSString *)field2
          withField3:(NSString *)field3
          withField4:(NSString *)field4 {


    char *err;
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ('%@' " "TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER '%@' TEXT);", tableName, field1, field2, field3, field4];

    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Table created");

    }



}

-(void)openDB {

    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open");

    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }
}

- (NSString *)filePath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sql"];

}
```

My sqlite3_errmsg output is:

```
2013-06-25 15:13:57.174 BPApp[12400:c07] Error message is: table summary has no column named comments
```

Which doesn't make sense to me.  I seem to be creating it just fine.

Comment: Where is the database file? Perhaps you should show your `openDB` method. If the file is in the your app's resource bundle then keep in mind that it will be read-only.

Comment: Also note that it is a very bad practice to use string formats to build your query. It's much better to use prepared statements and bind the values into the query using the various `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions`.

Comment: I just updated the code to show the openDB method.

Comment: But now you need to show the `filePath` method.

Comment: My apologies.  Thanks very much for your quick response.

Comment: Update your assertion to include the output of the `sqlite3_errmsg` function. Call that before closing the database.

Comment: Code has been updated.  sqlite3_errmsg is: 2013-06-25 15:13:57.174 BPApp[12400:c07] Error message is: table summary has no column named comments

Comment: OK, now you know the problem.

Comment: But this doesn't make sense.  I distinctly create the column, "comments" in my method "createTable" which I call from my viewDidLoadMethod: [self createTable:@"summary" withField1:@"theDate" withField2:@"systolic" withField3:@"diastolic" withField4:@"comments"];

Comment: rmaddy, I figured out my error, and I was able to find it because you helped me identify it.  Can you please post your comment suggesting I use sqlite3_errmsg to identify the error before I close the database as a solution, so that I may award you the points?  From the error message, I found out that I left out a comma in my table creation sql statement, which is why the comments column was not being created.  Thanks again for your help!